# $C^{\infty}$ function represented by the diverging integral

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

There is a theorem (see Treves: "Introduction to Pseudodifferential and Fourier integral operators") that states that the kernel of any pseudodifferential operator, i.e. the distribution
$$
  K(x,y) = \int e^{i(x-y)\xi} a(x,y,\xi){\,\rm d}\xi
$$
is the $C^{\infty}$ function on the complement to the diagonal of $\Omega \times \Omega$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. But what it means if the integral diverges?

Comment: If we consider an operator $Au (x,y) = \int e^{i(x-y)\xi} a(x,y,\xi) d\xi$ then $K(x,y)$ may be considered as it's continuous extension to the class of tempered functions.